# C++, variadic templates, passing platform-specific command-line arguments with the same code

Tags: c++, templates, architecture, variadic-templates, software-design

I have my main game engine class Rage, which has an instance of a PlatformManager class. I want PlatformManager to be the only point onwards where platform-specific code is run, and Rage to be as independent as possible.

I need to pass command-line arguments to PlatformManager, and these arguments will change depending on the platform (PlatformManager can then break-down any user commands and use callbacks to notify RAGE or whatever, seems cleaner than the logic being in Rage). I was trying to convert Rage and PlatformManager to use variadic templates so that I could pass in whatever arguments to Rage which would forward them to PlatformManager, and separating implementation of each into their respective source files. With explicit instantiation I could control what instances of Rage the user could create per-platform to make sure they pass in the correct arguments, whilst keeping the rest of the Rage class exactly the same across platforms.

(Please excuse any bugs as I'm new to templating, this is more an architecture question)

**RAGE.hpp**

```
template<typename... Args>
class Rage : public PlatformManagerDelegate
{
    PlatformManager<Args...> platformManager;
    //other variables...

public:
    Rage(Args... args);
    //other methods...
};
```

**RAGE.cpp**

```
template<typename... Args>
Rage<Args...>::Rage(Args... args) : platformManager<args>
{
    //Link modules together, set delegates e.t.c
    platformManager.delegate = this;
    //other code...
}

//other methods...

template class Rage<>; //General explicit instantiation
#if defined RAGE_WINDOWS
template class Rage<int, char*[]>; //Platform-specific explicit instantiation
#elif defined RAGE_ANDROID
template class Rage<struct android_app*>; //Platform-specific explicit instantiation
#endif
```

**PlatformManager.hpp**

```
class PlatformManagerDelegate
{
public:
    //Some delegate methods which Rage definitely implements...
};
inline PlatformManagerDelegate::~PlatformManagerDelegate() {}

template<typename... Args>
class PlatformManager : public WindowManagerDelegate
{
public:
    PlatformManagerDelegate *delegate;
    //other variables...

    PlatformManager(Args... args);
    //other methods...
};
```

**PlatformManager.cpp**

```
template<typename... Args>
PlatformManager<Args...>::PlatformManager(Args... args) : delegate(0)
{
    //Do whatever...
}

//Other methods...

template class PlatformManager<>;
//plus whatever platform-specific explicit instantiations - PlatformManager class is different on each platform
```

**main.cpp**

```
Rage<struct android_app*> clientInstance(appState); //Instance on Android
//OR
Rage<int, char*[]> clientInstance(argc, argv); //Instance on Windows

clientInstance.beginRun();
```

I found that this gave me issues as I have C-style pointers (yes I know, bad) around my engine so that other classes can interact with PlatformManager, and couldn't figure out how to create a pointer to a class template without using an explicit instance

```
template<typename... Args> PlatformManager<Args...> *platformManager; //Doesn't work
```

I'm now thinking of just scrapping templates and #ifdef-fing separate constructors in Rage that will take platform-specific command-line arguments, but this feels dirty, and doing it around explicit instances of template classes per-platform feels nicer, as the code would stay the same. This is a long post for essentially a very simple problem, but I'm wondering what the "best" way to architect this type of problem would be, as I can imagine choosing the "wrong" way for a similar but larger problem would be costly.

Comment: Your program arguments are provided at *run* time. the arguments for a variadic template parameter pack are provided at *compile* time. I've seen some template aficionados pull some amazing rabbits out of hats, but I'm not sure this one is doable.

Comment: Yes but by using explicit instantiation in a per-platform way, I can compile different versions of my Rage engine class that will match the parameters of said platform. For instance for Windows would this `template class Rage<int, char*[]>;` not do the job, or am I way off here?

Comment: I'd prefer conditionally compiled constructors taking platform specific arguments to the explicit template instantiations you have right now. To avoid repeating code, you could just extract the required info from the constructor arguments within these constructors, and then call a common function that does the majority of the work with the extracted info.

Comment: A problem (or not really a problem, but something I dislike) with that method is that the header will show all constructors for different platforms, however thinking about the way I have things now a user wouldn't even know how they should create a Rage instance per-platform without looking at some sort of documentation or guessing with the platform's command line parameters, so I think the conditionally compiled constructors has a win in that department (I'm half asleep right now so I might be talking rubbish). Any reason why you would prefer your choice?

Comment: If it were me, I'd go in a more "dependency injection" flavored direction, where `Rage` only holds a handle (ie. reference or `unique_ptr<>`) to a `PlatformManager` object it's given at construction time, rather than `Rage` acting as a proxy for `PlatformManager`.  That way, `PlatformManager` just defines the interface, and you can have `AndroidPlatformManager`, `WindowsPlatformManager`, whatever defined far, far away from your engine, and only compile and link the one you need.  After all, `main` is likely unique for different platforms anyway, and you can construct the right one there.

Comment: Me, I would write the argument parser somewhere, and have it output mostly platform agnostic data.  Do it asap, and get that out of the way.  This may not work perfectly, but it would be my first stab at it.

Comment: Joe Z - I see, I never considered that. Have the user create a PlatformManager instance that takes the command-line parameters and does what it needs to with them, then pass this object into their Rage instance. Interesting! Either way from all of these responses, I think the way I was approaching it with templating and stuff was bad and there are definitely better designs!